# Sending form data with guzzle throws server error

Tags: php, guzzle6

I'm sending form data, "packed" in URL using Guzzle to my JasperReports which is installed on another server. URL consists of form data and it's super long.

All the time, I'm receiving 500 Internal Server Error.

```
 $headers = [
           'url' => $url,
       ];

 this->client = new Client(['base_uri' => 'http://localhost:8080/jasper-r/report.jsp?id=0']);

       try {
           $promise = $this->client->request('POST', ["headers" => $headers]);
           return response($promise->message_id);
       } catch (RequestException $e) {
           return abort($e->getMessage());
```

Comment: What does the error log say?

Comment: parse_url() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Because of that: $headers = [ 'url' => $url ]; If I change it with $promise = $this->client->request('POST', $url);   still the same error will occur and I will receive The HTTP status code "0" is not valid.